# Validate BelongsToMany attached keys exists

Tags: laravel, validation, has-and-belongs-to-many

How to validate foreign keys (as UUID) in attached elements like below:

```
$user->languages()->attach([
    '9a347a21-b6db-42ae-85a5-24a270946eec' => [ // UUID of language
        'additional_field' => 2,
        'additional_field2' => '',
    ],
    '9a347a21-e0b8-4475-a262-e63042d1a6f6' => [ // UUID of language
        'additional_field' => 321,
        'additional_field2' => 'aaa bb c',
    ],
]);
```

My relation in `User` looks like:

```
public function languages(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class)
        ->using(UserLanguage::class)
        ->withPivot(['additional_field', 'additional_field2']);
}
```

I can validate by

- `languages`
- `languages.*.additional_field`
- `languages.*.additional_field2`

But how to validate UUID in above example is exists in Language model?

Answer (score 0):

The `exists` validation should work the same way as it does with regular numeric ids. However, it gets tricky to validate if you pass the ids as array keys.

One way I'd do it is like this

```
'languages' => ['array'],
'languages.*' => ['array'],
'languages.*.language_uuid' => ['required', 'exists:languages,uuid'],
'languages.*.pivot' => ['array'],
'languages.*.pivot.additional_field' => [...],
'languages.*.pivot.additional_field2' => [...],
```

The data sent would look like

```json
"languages": [
    [
        "language_uuid": "9a347a21-b6db-42ae-85a5-24a270946eec",
        "pivot": {
            "additional_field": 2,
            "additional_field2": ""
        }
    ],
    [
        "language_uuid": "9a347a21-e0b8-4475-a262-e63042d1a6f6",
        "pivot": {
            "additional_field": 321,
            "additional_field2": "aaa bb c"
        }
    ],
]
```

And the way you could easily insert stuff in the endpoint with the validated request would be

```php
$validated = $request->validated();
$user = User::create($validated); // The languages key being present here shouldn't be a problem if you've defined which fields are fillable in the User model.

$languages = collect($validated['languages'])
    ->map(fn ($data) => [ $data['language_uuid'] => $data['pivot'] ])
    ->all();
$user->languages()->attach($languages);
```

---

Assuming you send the data like this:

```json
"languages": [
    "9a347a21-b6db-42ae-85a5-24a270946eec": {
        "additional_field": 2,
        "additional_field2": ""
    },
    "9a347a21-e0b8-4475-a262-e63042d1a6f6": {
        "additional_field": 321,
        "additional_field2": "aaa bb c"
    }
]
```

The only way I can think of that would validate the keys without making a new Rule would be to use a Callback, like the `validator` or the `FormRequest`'s `after()` method.

[Laravel 10.x - Validation - Performing Additional Validation on Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#performing-additional-validation-on-form-requests)

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'languages' => ['array'],
        'languages.*' => ['array'],
        'languages.*.additional_field' => [...],
        'languages.*.additional_field2' => [...],
    ];
}

public function after()
{
    return [
        function (Validator $validator) {
            $uuids = array_keys($validator->getData()['languages']);

            foreach ($uuids as $uuid) {
                if (Language::where('uuid', $uuid)->doesntExist()) {
                    $validator->errors()->add(
                        "languages.{$uuid}",
                        __('validation.exists', ['attribute' => 'language uuid']),
                    );

                    return;
                }
            }
        }.
    ];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but there is no solutions without modify data, to save structure required by attach?

Comment: Not without creating your own validation rule

Comment: Although, assuming this is happening inside a form request you could use a callback.